# Navigation covers main content

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

When I shrink the window, the right nav menu covers the main content

Here is the image in its usual state
[image]

The image when the window is reduced is as follows

[image]

Here is the code for default.vue

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
    <Header />
    <div class="d-flex flex-0-1-100">
      <SideMenu />
      <v-main class="pl-0 pr-0">
        <v-container>
          <slot />
          <NavigationLink />
        </v-container>
      </v-main>
      <TableofContents />
    </div>
    <Footer />
  </v-app>
</template>
<style lang="scss">
.test {
}
.v-main {
  border-left: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-right: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
video {
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

TableofContents.vue for right navigation menu code is below

```html
<template>
  <v-navigation-drawer
    permanent
    location="right"
    border="none"
    class="position-sticky"
    :style="{ maxHeight, minWidth }"
    style="height: fit-content"
    width="250"
  >
    <v-list>
      <v-list-item>
        <v-list-item-title class="ml-6">Table of Contents</v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item>
      <v-list-item>
        <div class="ml-6 green">
          <nuxt-link
            v-for="(id, index) in filteredIds"
            :key="id"
            :to="`#${id}`"
            class="toc-contents text-decoration-none d-block"
            :class="{ visible: isVisible[index] }"
            >{{ id }}</nuxt-link
          >
        </div>
      </v-list-item>
    </v-list>
  </v-navigation-drawer>
</template>

<style scoped lang="scss">
.toc-contents {
  color: $color-gray-100;
}
.visible {
  color: $color-toc-text-visible;
}
</style>
```

I would appreciate it if you could tell me if there is a way to improve this

The image when minWidth is deleted from  of TableofContents.vue is as follows

[image]

Comment: I think the problem comes from the `minWidth` on the right nav drawer. Not sure if there is another way than just removing it

Comment: @MoritzRingler 
Thank you for your advice. If you remove minWidth, the navigation disappears when you shrink the window.

Comment: Hmm, when I try it out, it shrinks, but it does not disappear. Do you have a playground that demonstrates the behavior?

Comment: I have created a repository for the purpose of reproducing the issue. If possible, I would greatly appreciate it if you could take a look and confirm the situation using the following link:
https://github.com/newyee/nuxt-site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem seems to be the `minWidth` on the nav-drawer.

Have a look at the [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) to see how it behaves without it.

---

Alternatively, you can allow the main container to shrink (per default, it can only grow):

```html
<v-main
  class="px-0 flex-shrink-1"
  ...
```

This works well with a `minWidth` on the nav-drawer, as it allows to reduce size of the main area when the navs can't shrink any further.

Here is [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind response.

However, based on my own testing, the right navigation disappeared. In order to accurately convey the situation, I have created a Git repository for reproducing the issue.

If possible, could you please take a look at the following repository to verify the situation? I apologize for any inconvenience this may cause and appreciate your assistance.

https://github.com/newyee/nuxt-site

Comment: When I try to run it, I get *ERROR  Cannot start nuxt:  [@nuxtjs/algolia] Missing apiKey.*

Comment: I'm sorry. Please create a .env file and copy all the contents of .env.example.

Comment: Afterwards, please run the "npm install" command and then "npm run dev" command. By doing so, you should be able to confirm using the following URL:
http://localhost:3000/ja/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Ah, got it, thank you. Turns out main area cannot shrink, have a look at the updated answer

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. It was really helpful and I appreciate it. I apologize for any inconvenience. I've confirmed that I was able to resolve the issue in my own environment

Comment: Oh, it wasn't inconvenient at all, it worked nicely I think, exactly as you described. Glad it resolved the issue!

Comment: I apologize for the repeated requests. I'm actually stuck on the following two parts, so if possible, could you please take a look?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77007604/how-to-modify-the-left-and-right-navigation-menu-layout
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77013036/display-of-table-of-contents-for-responsive-does-not-work