# How to modify the left and right navigation menu layout

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

There are two issues that I would like to address:

The first issue is that when scrolling to the very bottom, the left navigation menu disappears above.

The second issue occurs when the window is resized, causing the right navigation menu to overlap with the main content.
[image]

The repository in question can be found at: https://github.com/newyee/nuxt-site. Furthermore, due to company policy, the content area that includes both left and right navigation menus needs to have a width of 1190px. Therefore, this width has been set to 1190px in default.vue, as seen here: https://github.com/newyee/nuxt-site/blob/main/layouts/default.vue#L74.

Comment: When I run your project and go to http://localhost:3000/ja/getting-started/introduction/ it gives me `Cannot find module './src/algoliasearch.helper'`

Comment: @MoritzRingler
I apologize. Could you please provide the .env file as follows?
NUXT_BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000
ALGOLIA_INDEX_NAME=test,
ALGOLIA_SEARCH_ONLY_API_KEY=test
ALGOLIA_APPLICATION_ID=test
LOCAL_SERVER=true

Comment: @MoritzRingler
I apologize for any inconvenience, and I'm sorry to ask for your help again, but if you still encounter errors, please try deleting the node_modules directory and the .nuxt directory once more, and then run "npm install" and "npm run dev" again.

Comment: Hmm, still not running locally, even when starting from a new clone. It works in a sandbox though. The first issue I don't understand, only the unused space under the closed second menu is removed, the menu does not disappear when I try it out. The second issue comes from the `width=1190px` on the .main-content container. Consider using `max-width`/`min-width` instead

Comment: @MoritzRingler
Thank you very much. I apologize for repeatedly asking, but I have what might be a rather forward request. I'm really keen on getting some local confirmation, as I'm trying to resolve an issue with running the project in my local environment. Therefore, I'm considering creating a new question to seek assistance with this specific local execution problem. I truly appreciate your understanding of the inconvenience I'm causing.

Comment: @MoritzRingler

I asked a question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77016251/error-occurring-when-accessing-specific-url-after-cloning-and-running-nuxt-js-re

Comment: @MoritzRingler
I've commented out the part of algoliasearch.helper related to the error content and pushed it to the remote repository. Could you please take a look again when you have a moment? Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: @MoritzRingler
I have uploaded it to Netlify for reproducibility.
You can access it here: https://document-driven-demo.netlify.app/ja/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: Oh, as I said, I already had it working in a sandbox (you can turn github urls into sandboxes by adding "box" to the url: githubbox.com/...).

Comment: @MoritzRingler
I'm sorry.
I didn't know there was a feature called "githubbox." It's the first time I've heard of it.
Regarding the advice you gave me about specifying the max-width, I tried it out, and it solved the first issue, which was the problem of the right navigation overlapping the main content.
However, the issue of the left navigation hiding when scrolling all the way to the bottom is still unresolved.
https://github.com/newyee/nuxt-site/blob/main/layouts/default.vue#L113

Comment: @MoritzRingler

Thank you for your frequent advice!

I've posted a new question, but if it doesn't get resolved with this, I'll put this issue on hold for now.

Here's the link to the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77041190/the-top-of-the-left-navigation-menu-is-hidden-when-scrolling

Thanks to the answers I've received so far, I've been able to shape the application and it has been a great help to me.