# Error Occurring When Accessing Specific URL After Cloning and Running Nuxt.js Repository

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I received a comment that an error occurs when accessing the URL "http://localhost:3000/ja/getting-started/introduction/" after cloning and running the repository at https://github.com/newyee/nuxt-site. However, I am not experiencing this error in my environment.

Here are the detailed steps after cloning the repository:

1. Navigate to the cloned directory: cd nuxt-site
2. Copy the example environment file: cp .env.example .env
3. Install dependencies: npm install
4. Run the development server: npm run dev
   I would appreciate it if you could check if others are also experiencing this error in their environments. If possible, please verify and confirm. Thank you.