# The upper part of the left navigation menu is hidden

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

When scrolling to the very bottom of the page, the top of the left navigation menu gets hidden.

The image before scrolling is shown below:
[image]

The following image is after scrolling:

[image]

I'm not sure about the exact cause of this issue, so I would appreciate any advice or assistance in identifying and resolving it.

For reproduction confirmation, the deployed URL here:

https://document-driven-demo.netlify.app/ja/getting-started/introduction/

The complete code is stored in the GitHub repository below:

https://github.com/newyee/nuxt-site

Comment: It's working fine on my end. It does not hide the left menu

Comment: @ReaganM
sorry. English was not good and was not communicated well.
The display itself is completed, but when you scroll to the bottom, the upper part of the left navigation menu seems to be filled up.

Comment: There should be a scrollbar in the left container - is there? Overall, when height of the navigation exceeds the available space, the overflow has to go somewhere. Where would you expect it to go?

Comment: @MoritzRingler
Thank you for your comments.
--There should be a scrollbar in the left container - is there?--
Regarding this response, for example, if there were many other menu items in addition to "Getting Started" and "examples" in the left navigation menu of a page like "https://document-driven-demo.netlify.app/en/getting-started/introduction/", I would expect a scrollbar to appear.

Comment: @MoritzRingler
--when height of the navigation exceeds the available space, the overflow has to go somewhere. Where would you expect it to go?--
As for this, it's a bit of a challenging question for me, and I don't quite understand it myself.

Comment: The scrollbar appears when the sidebar height exceeds height of window minus header

Comment: @MoritzRingler
Thank you very much. It was very educational.

Comment: @MoritzRingler
I greatly appreciate your help in advancing the development of the application. I apologize for the frequent requests, but if it's possible, could you also take a look at the following question?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77050616/how-to-specify-border-on-footer

Comment: @MoritzRingler 
Sorry for the request for confirmation, but I have recreated it anew here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77065742/how-to-fix-the-border-line-on-the-footer?noredirect=1#comment135858875_77065742"